# Cannot select text of TextBox control with mouse

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-2.0

I want to embed a `Form` within another `Form`. Here is what I have tried:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form = new Form2();  
    form.TopLevel = false;  
    panel1.Controls.Add(form);  
    form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;  
    form.Show();  
}
```

`Form1` is the parent form. `Form2` is the child form, which has a `TextBox` control.

**The problem:** After embedding the child form, the `TextBox` in the child form cannot be selected with the mouse.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your code doesn't repro the problem.

Comment: Why you call panel1.Controls.Add(form) ? Does panel1 have any special properties set ?

Answer (score 1):

I Googled the problem. From my research I concluded that it's not a good idea to embed a `Form` within a `Panel`. I took another approach and have now made the child `Form` as an [MDI](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mdi/info) child.

Comment: Apparently another option is to set `FormBorderStyle = None` on `Form2`... which probably defeats the purpose since the behavior will be all wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3075762/945456

Answer (score -1):

You need to setup the parent of the Form before calling .Show()

form.Parent = this;

Comment: Thank for your reply. This way didn't fix the problem.

Comment: We have the same problem as well and were already doing this.