# Textbox all properties not working when textbox added in other control

Tags: vb.net, textbox, panel

I have added a windows form on control panel using following code

```
Dim frmopen As New WinForm1
panel1.Controls.Add(frmopen)
```

Form opens normally work also but my concern is,
I have one textbox on that WinForm1, when i am typing text in that textbox it takes input but when i am clicking in between that typed text the cursor goes to either last character or first character.

So if i have to enter characters in between, then first i have to erase the typed characters and then i have to type again.

Plz help me to work textbox normally??

Thank you

Comment: did you hook up some event handlers?

Comment: You must have some event/binding hooked up. This is not the normal behavior of the textbox. Seems like the text is being re-displayed after a focus or a click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the child form's FormBorderStyle to None.

See: [Windows Forms: Unable to Click to Focus a MaskedTextBox in a Non TopLevel Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875075/windows-forms-unable-to-click-to-focus-a-maskedtextbox-in-a-non-toplevel-form)

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim frm2 As New Form2
    frm2.TopLevel = False
    frm2.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(frm2)
    frm2.Show()

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: But what if i don't wan't to remove  FormBorderStyle